# Your node is 2540154 blocks behind (9.7 years) - even though it is not?

Tags: monerod, full-node, error-log

I get this message that my node is 9.7 years behind even though it is at the current height.

Does this just mean that this IP is trying to send me wrong block height data?

LOG:
IP.Address:18080[OUT] sync data returned a new top block candidate: 3098243 -> 5638397 [Your node is 2540154 blocks behind (9.7 years) behind]
Synchronization started

Will the node know to check other nodes to see if this larger height number 5638397 is correct/incorrect or should I block that IP?

This happened couple days ago so I know the current height is not 3098243.

Edit: added a better title to this ask.